# finding the address of a function in import table

Tags: ollydbg

I want to find the line of a specific function in IAT.
When I open that executable with ollydbg and go to import table section, I see a very long list of functions. However I cant figure out how to find the specific function I'm looking for.
How it is done?

Answer (score 1):

alt+e ----> select the module of interest

ctrl+n ----> a new window with all the resolved name pops up

start typing the name of function you are interested in

i typed TerminateProcess and ollydbg scrolled that function into view

```
Names in calc, item 147
  Address = 003A128C
  Section = .text
  Type = Import
  Ordinal =
  Name = &KERNEL32.TerminateProcess
  Comments =
```